# Merge vhost and virtualhost

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are different tags for [vhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vhost) and [virtualhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualhost), but these seem largely the same tag. They should be synonymed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having paged through all of [vhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vhost), I believe you are right. Time to take a good look at things.

Right then. I noticed [vhosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vhosts) was there too, doing the same thing. It's been merged in as well.